# Base class with class method call closure with child class type

Tags: swift, generics

I have a base class with a class func:

```
class BaseModel
{
    class func getObjectWithId(_ id: String, completionHandler: @escaping (<???>) -> ())
    {
       // does query, calls completionHandler with matching object
    }
}
```

I have two child classes:

```
class Cat: BaseModel { //whatever }
class Dog: BaseModel { //whatever }
```

I want to be able to call that class method on the child classes and have the completion handler called with an object of the child's type:

```
Cat.getObjectWithId("1") { (theCat) in
 // I want theCat to be of type Cat, not BaseModel
}

Dog.getObjectWithId("1") { (theDog) in
 // I want theDog to be of type Dog, not BaseModel
}
```

I tinkered with generics, but admit it's not my strength...

- I do NOT want to have to write code for this in every base class b/c it's identical except for the type (i.e. I don't want a protocol that each child has to implement).
- I do NOT want one class method that takes the type as an argument.  I really really like the simplicity of my example method calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
class BaseModel
{
    class func getObjectWithId<T: BaseModel>(_ id: String, completionHandler: @escaping (T) -> ())
    {
       // does query, calls completionHandler with matching object
    }
}
```

But you have to explicitly specialise types like this

```
Cat.getObjectWithId("1") { (theCat: Cat) in
    // I want theCat to be of type Cat, not BaseModel
}

Dog.getObjectWithId("1") { (theDog: Dog) in
    // I want theDog to be of type Dog, not BaseModel
}
```

But more safe way is to duplicate function `getObjectWithId` in every class you want.

Comment: Of the two answers so far, this looks better...although I'm not thrilled with the caller basically having to cast it to the correct type.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer b/c it gave me a working example of the generic signature and got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a hybrid approach between Anton's suggestion and doing a bit of what I originally didn't want to do:

1. I created the base version of the method almost exactly as Anton had, except it also requires the data type (something I originally wanted to avoid):

   ```
   class BaseModel
   {
       class func getObjectWithId<T: BaseModel>(_ id: String, type: T.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (T?) -> ())
       {
          // does query, calls completionHandler with matching object
       }
   }
   ```
2. Child classes then have their own specialized method that calls that base class method:

   ```
   class Dog: BaseModel
   {
       class func getDogWithId(_ dogId: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Dog?) -> ()
       {
           BaseModel.getObjectWithId(dogId, objectType: Dog.self) { (dog) in
           completionHandler(dog)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Con: It's annoying to create a signature for this method in every child class (it's not even inheritance anymore, though I still need the base class for other reasons).

Pro: It's nice in that I don't have to repeat the guts of the code in each child class,

Pro: I don't have to cast the results every time I call the child class method.